# Count unique occurrences within data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, tabulate

Let the table be as follows:

| v1 | v2 | v3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | A |
| B | B | A |
|  | A | C |
| D | C | D |

What i want R to create a table for number of occurences of unique values for each column:

| v1 | v2 | v3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 2 |
| C | 0 | 1 |
| D | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be:

```
sapply(df, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = unique(unlist(df)))))

  V1 v2 v3
A  1  1  2
B  1  2  0
D  1  0  1
C  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `table` like this

```
> table(unlist(df),names(df)[col(df)])

    V1 v2 v3
  A  1  1  2
  B  1  2  0
  C  0  1  1
  D  1  0  1
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c("A", "B", NA, "D"), v2 = c("B", "B", "A", 
"C"), v3 = c("A", "A", "C", "D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the set, a tidyverse version.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    everything(), 
    values_to="Value", 
    names_to="Variable"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Variable, Value) %>% 
  summarise(N=n(), .groups="drop") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from=N, names_from=Variable, values_fill=0) %>% 
  arrange(Value)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Value    v1    v2    v3
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 A         1     1     2
2 B         1     2     0
3 C         0     1     1
4 D         1     0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is an approach which uses a combination of `melt()` and `dcast()`:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df1), measure.vars = patterns("^v"))[value != ""], value ~ variable)
```

> ```
>    value v1 v2 v3
> 1:     A  1  1  2
> 2:     B  1  2  0
> 3:     C  0  1  1
> 4:     D  1  0  1
> ```

The approach is similar to [Limey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68652722/3817004) in reshaping the data from wide to long and back to wide but less verbose.

#### Edit

Instead of `dcast()`, `table()` can be called after reshaping from wide to long:

```
melt(setDT(df1), measure.vars = patterns("^v"))[value != ""][
  , table(value, variable)]
```

> ```
>      variable
> value v1 v2 v3
>     A  1  1  2
>     B  1  2  0
>     C  0  1  1
>     D  1  0  1
> ```

Note that *data.table chaining* is used here.

And, to save a few keystrokes:

```
melt(setDT(df1), measure.vars = names(df1))[value != ""][, table(rev(.SD))]
```

#### Data

```
df1 <- fread("
|v1|v2|v3|
|A |B | A|
|B |B | A|
|  |A | C|
|D |C | D|", 
drop = c(1,5), header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
 t(mtabulate(df))
  V1 v2 v3
A  1  1  2
B  1  2  0
C  0  1  1
D  1  0  1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "B", NA, "D"), v2 = c("B", "B", "A", 
"C"), v3 = c("A", "A", "C", "D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-4L))
```